# Last two row from multiple records assistance

Tags: sql, t-sql

I’m having a little problem that I’m not sure how to get a round and hoping someone here can assist. What I need to do is run a select on multiple records and retrieve the last two records of p.CustID. When enter in one p.CustID the code works fine however I need to remove the where clause and I need it to retrieve the last two records for each p.CustID (about 14,000 records in total) When I remove the where clause it only returns two records in total which are top two records in my from statement [DB_User].[dbo].[P1ASellers]. I tried using this in a CTE but still cannot get this to return
Code I’m using below:
    `SELECT TOP (2)
    cbc.StorePartnerCustConfigID,
    p.CustID,
    cbc.ConfigID,
    cbc.EffectiveDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cbc.StorePartnerID DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM [DB_User].[dbo].[P1ASellers] p
    INNER JOIN [ACA].dbo.tblConfig_StorePartnerConfig BP
    ON BP.EntityID=CAST(p.CustID AS VARCHAR)
    INNER JOIN [ACA].dbo.tblConfig_StorePartner CBP
    ON CBP.StorePartnerID=BP.StorePartnerID
    INNER JOIN [ACA].dbo.tblConfig_StorePartnerCustConfig CBC
    ON CBP.StorePartnerID=CBC.StorePartnerID
    AND cbc.ProcessConfigID IN (1,2,3,4)
    INNER JOIN [ACA].dbo.tblConfig_StorePartnerCustConfig CBC2
    ON CBC.StorePartnerID=CBC2.StorePartnerID
    AND cbc2.ConfigID IN (1,2,3,4) where p.CustID=55555 <-need to remove the 
    where
    ORDER BY cbc.StorePartnerID DESC`

The results from the query
StorePartnerCustConfigID   CustID      ConfigID    EffectiveDate   RowNum
15031                       55555          4        2015-06-25       1
15032                       55555          1        2015-06-25       2

What I actually get after I remove the where clause:
StorePartnerCustConfigID   CustID      ConfigID    EffectiveDate   RowNum
68995                       89566          2        2011-03-02       1
68996                       89566          1        2011-03-02       2

what I expect after I remove the where clause:
StorePartnerCustConfigID   CustID      ConfigID    EffectiveDate   RowNum
15031                       55555          4        2015-06-25       1
15032                       55555          1        2015-06-25       2
64584                       65486          2        2013-04-16       1
64585                       65486          1        2013-04-16       2
So on and so on.......

Any input greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for top 2 records for each customer which you can get as below:

```
SELECT TOP (2) with ties
    cbc.StorePartnerCustConfigID,
    p.CustID,
    cbc.ConfigID,
    cbc.EffectiveDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cbc.StorePartnerID DESC) AS RowNum
FROM [DB_User].[dbo].[P1ASellers] p
INNER JOIN [ACA].dbo.tblConfig_StorePartnerConfig BP
    ON BP.EntityID=CAST(p.CustID AS VARCHAR)
INNER JOIN [ACA].dbo.tblConfig_StorePartner CBP
    ON CBP.StorePartnerID=BP.StorePartnerID
INNER JOIN [ACA].dbo.tblConfig_StorePartnerCustConfig CBC
    ON CBP.StorePartnerID=CBC.StorePartnerID
    AND cbc.ProcessConfigID IN (1,2,3,4)
INNER JOIN [ACA].dbo.tblConfig_StorePartnerCustConfig CBC2
    ON CBC.StorePartnerID=CBC2.StorePartnerID
    AND cbc2.ConfigID IN (1,2,3,4) 
ORDER (row_number() over(partition by p.CustId Order BY cbc.StorePartnerID DESC-1)/2 +1 )
```